# What do I need to do to make my C# code run in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know this is very basic. I am trying to learn C# using Visual Studio for Mac. I've only ever used VS Code. I am trying to run the hello world program and for the life of me I can't figure out how to run it. Online and in videos they have a green play button that runs the code and displays in the console. For me, I have a play button, but all it does is say "Build Successful". Note I am on MacOS, I don't see anything under file up above either. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: What I see]

I have tried looking up above though the File, Edit, etc. but there is nothing there.

Comment: go to the project directory(it contains a *.csproj file) using terminal and run `dotnet run`, see if it works

Comment: @AliSalehi I just tried that and it worked. I thought that there would be a button in the editor so I wouldn't have to navigate using terminal. Is there a button that I'm missing?

Comment: yes there should be a run button and a build button, is your software up to date?have you tried to create another project ?

Comment: @gtighe: the play button in your screenshot is the right button. In bottom right of your screenshot you see the `Terminal - New`, your output should be there.

Comment: I think your code is running. but its exiting as well. try putting a breakpoint or add `Console.ReadLine()` and then run

Comment: I think it would be useful to clarify in the title that this is "Visual Studio for Mac" which is a *very* different product from normal Visual Studio.

Comment: There *is* a button in the editor. It's the Play button at the top left. The option to debug or run is also available in the application's menu. You can search for menu items and features from the Search textbox that appears at the top right

Answer (score 1):

I was very confused when I first try to use VS for Mac too. Everything seemed to be in the wrong place.

The button in the editor you're looking for is the Play button at the top left of the screenshot. The Configuration selector next to it is `Debug` which means `Play` will start debugging the application. The options are available in the application's menus as well, in the `Run` menu.

Check [Debugging with Visual Studio for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/debugging?view=vsmac-2022)

The reason for this confusion is that Visual Studio for Mac is actually Xamarin Studio rebranded as Visual Studio. The IDE was built following MacOS conventions, menus and shortcuts. The IDE is still focused on Xamarin development primarily.

You should consider using JetBrains Rider alongside VS for Mac. Both IDEs have their strengths and weaknesses, with Rider being a better all-around IDE but VS for Mac getting some core features, eg Blazor WASM debugging, earlier